# What are the pros and cons of a Relational DB vs Mongo vs Flat file behind a CDN

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, scalability, cdn, flat-file

let's say that I have an ecommerce website with million of products, that have millions of pageviews a day, mostly for product details pages.

Let's say that I currently have all my data in a relational DB, the old good way.

What would be the pros and cons of keeping the data in the relational DB for doing queries, aggreating and filtering products and all that...but using flat json files for the product details?

So, having 1 file per 1 product, with all details serialized to json. These files would be placed under a high-performance cdn, geographically distributed and all that. When the user goes to

www.mysite.com/prods/00123

the server (or even the client) would load a template file for the layout, and then fill it with the data it reads from something like cdn.mysite.com/prods/00123.json

So I basically don't need to do queries in this case - I jump straight to the file named after the product id. I guess it should be very fast, and yet I would delegate the scalability / caching / geographic distribution to an external strong partner (cdn like akamai, amazon etc.) instead of building my own (expensive and hard to maintain) distributed db server?

I look forward to your suggestions / feedback...especially if it comes to real world experience :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirements,

It is better to store product descriptions in a schema free database like MongoDB since your products can have very different fields with wide variation in number of attributes (and corresponding fields). Also such information is written far less often then they are read. MongoDB has collection level write locks which deter write heavy applications if you like to do consistent writes. However the reads in MongoDB are very fast because you dont have to do joins or fetch field values from a EAV schema table. Needless to say, based on your data volume sharding and replication needs to be done in a production environment.

It is better than storing in a flat file since MongoDB's read performance is very good because of memory mapped files and you get replication/sharding as well.

However, if the filesystem (or the filesystem network) provides the security, speed and accessibility provided by the database then storing the data in filesystem is not a bad idea. The traditional db vs flat-file argument does not hold true if the flat files are configured to be served in an efficient manner.

However, you should not store information like shopping cart, checkout transaction, etc in MongoDB since you dont have ACID transactions and frequent writes and updates 'with consistency' is not MongoDB's cup of tea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but let me reply:

Comment: >> It is better to store product descriptions in a schema free database
>> like MongoDB since your products can have very different fields with
>> wide variation in number of attributes (and corresponding fields). 

what's the problem in having 1 file for each product, even if they have different fields?? Each file will have its ow json...which is the same of having it stored in a MongoDB...no?

Comment: >> Also such information is written far less often then they are read. MongoDB has
>> collection level write locks which deter write heavy applications if you like to 
>> do consistent writes. However the reads in MongoDB are very fast because you dont
>> have to do joins or fetch field values from a EAV schema table.

I'd have one file per product, with all the required data. So no joins, filters or anything like that. The question is: is getting a document from MongoDB actually faster than reading a direct file from the filesystem, where the file is named after the document id?

Comment: >> Needless to say, based on your data volume sharding and replication needs to 
>> be done in a production environment. It is better than storing in a flat file since
>> MongoDB's read performance is very good because of memory mapped files and you get
>> replication/sharding as well.

replied above about performance....that's the only question actually.
And replication + geographic distribution would be done by the CDN...so I don't think there would be a real advantage of Mongo there?

Comment: Storing the data in filesystem with one json file for each product might be feasible since your dataset is not expected to be very large (~100 million rows) but depending on the volume of data and the underlying filesystem, your performance might vary. Of course if all your documents dont fit in a single filesystem, you have to do manual sharding (NFS?). Its the age old question about whether its better to store data in flat files or databases.

Comment: You can try doing a simple benchmark using 100000 documents or so and see which is faster. Make sure you use file caching on the system where you are storing your files. If you do the benchmark, please send me the results link since I am very interested in knowing about fs vs db performance.

Comment: actually the caching will be done by the CDN....that's why I think it will be very fast...because I don't even need to access the raw file system that often....